# What are the project types supported by Windows store?

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Are only universal windows platform (UWP) applications supported by Windows store or normal desktop applications such as win32 are also supported?

Also what is the difference between win32 project and a general empty project? is it the same but just with a console in the output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are only universal windows platform (UWP) applications supported by
>   Windows store or normal desktop applications such as win32 are also
>   supported?

Currently the project types accepted by Windows Store include Windows universal apps for Windows 10 and 8.1 and Windows Phone Silverlight project:
[image]

For desktop application, only Win32 desktop apps using .NET 4.6.1 can be published to the Store via [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter).

After you generate your converted package, you need to fill out [this form](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge) and you'll acquire the permission to publish your package once your request gets verified.

> Also what is the difference between win32 project and a general empty
>   project? is it the same but just with a console in the output?

You might refer to the response from @Elegentin Xie in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ce711aa-6fc3-4437-bee9-7e8a6ff9204d/whats-the-difference-between-an-empty-project-and-win32-application?forum=vcgeneral), which indicate the difference between them.